# How to pass a callback without invoking ist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass a callback function. At moment it gets called before it gets passed. What is wrong?

```
<MyComponent callback={()=> console.log(1)} isDirty ={true} setCallback={()=>{}} />
```

Declaration

```
export function MyComponent({ ...props} ) {
  const { setCallback, callback, isDirty } = props
  const cancelCallback = isDirty ? () => setCallback(callback) : callback

  return (
    <>

        <Button onClick={cancelCallback}>Cancel</Button>

    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: How do you pass the callback function to "MyComponent"?

Comment: @NilsKoch I added that part in the question

Comment: A assume you are talking about the `callback` prop. In your code the function is not called immediately/when you pass it to `MyComponent`.

Comment: @FelixKling It gets called before it is used by setCallback. The debugger tells me it is called in line 3 const cancelCallback

Comment: Since you you neither call `setCallback` there nor `callback` it's not called there, at least not in the code you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replicated it on my system and it doesn't get called. One common mistake is to pass a callback function like this:

```js
callback={console.log(1)}
```

instead like this:

```js
callback={() => console.log(1)}
```

With this mistake the callback function gets called immediately.

Answer (score -2):

you need to update your click handler function.

```
const cancelCallback = () => {
  isDirty ? setCallback(callback) : callback();
};
```

Comment: That's equivalent to what the OP has.

Comment: No, What OP has is actually different if you can compare. It is actually making a function call directly rather than registering a function on click.

Comment: No it doesn't.  `const cancelCallback = isDirty ? () => setCallback(callback) : callback` either assigns `() => setCallback(callback)` (an arrow function) or `callback` (also a function). It's not calling a function at this point (calling `callback` would look like `callback()`, and calling the arrow function immediately would look like `(() => setCallback(callback))()`. This it yourself: `const callback = () => console.log('callback'); const cancelCallback = true/*false*/ ? () => console.log('inline') : callback;` (change `true` to `false` to test the other branch).